# Can I establish a two way connection between a node js server and a python server?

Tags: python, node.js, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I want to build a content based recommender system. The user is initially shown 5 items and based on what he clicks and what he likes, the data is then transferred to python server, processed and the next 5 items are selected accordingly and sent to node js server which are then displayed. 
Is it even possible to do this ? Or is there any better way to do this ? I have a huge data set which I ran a fuzzy c-means clustering algorithm and have them clustered across 10 classes.
I'm a noob. Please care to answer. Thanks.

Edit : Yes, I want to do the number crunching in python and want to serve the website in node.
 Detailed Explanation :
Say, I have a list of movies from 10 genres. And I do not have any other user data. The only data I get to feed the recommender system is the movie genres the user clicks and likes. The next set of movies to be displayed for him should be aligned a bit towards the movie genres he clicked  or liked and so on. 
Final goal : What percentage of his interest lies in each genre.

Edit 2: 
By node js server, I mean

"Web server can refer to either the hardware (the computer) or the software (the computer application) that helps to deliver content that can be accessed through the Internet.1

The primary function of a web server is to deliver web pages on the request to clients. This means delivery of HTML documents and any additional content that may be included by a document, such as images, style sheets and scripts."

I don't know if the word server is apt for python. But what I mean is, it has to get the user's likes in real time, process it and send the next set of items to node js.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What exactly do you mean by "python server" and "node.js server"? It's quite clear that you want to do the number crunching in python and serve the web site from node, but since you ask about an infrastructure, it's essential to know more about its building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to call some Python in a node enviroment.
You will need Node and Python installed on your machine. The code is this:

this is in the javascript file:

```
var util = require("util");

var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn("python",["some_python.py"]);

util.log('readingin')

process.stdout.on('data',function(chunk){

    var textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8');// buffer to string

    util.log(textChunk);
});
```

And this is the some_python.py file

```
import sys

data = "heloo python"
print(data)
sys.stdout.flush()
```